# Ruby - Create a class with a file as a variable - possible?

Tags: ruby, file, class

I need to create a program in which the user can take different tests. As i dont want to copy paste my code all over for every test, i have tried to setup a class for that purpose - but i have problems with this class. 
Error message =  undefined variables or method in 'display_test'

I have predefined som test as a .txt file

I want to choose the file in the class depending on what the user answer - is that possible?

Class code:

```
  class Test

    @correct_answers = 0

def display_question( question, options, answer )
  puts question
  options.each_with_index { |option, idx| puts "#{ idx + 1 }: #{ option
}" }
  print 'Answer: '
  reply = gets.to_i
  if answer == reply
    puts 'Correct!'
    @correct_answers += 1
    puts "#{@correct_answers}" 
  else
    puts 'Wrong. The correct answer was: ' + answer.to_s
  end
end



def display_test()
f = File.new(userinput, 'r')

while ! (f.eof?)        #logikken til at splitte
   line = f.gets()
   question = line.split("|")
   question[1] = question[1].split(";")
   display_question question[0], question[1], question[2].to_i
 end
end

display_test

puts "________________________________________________________"
puts "Total score:"

puts "You've got" + " #{@correct_answers}" + " correct answers!"
```

Before hand i have used ("geografitest.txt") instead of username in the File.new so it looked like this:

```
f = File.new('geografitest.txt','r')
```

But now i am trying to let the user decide what test to take.

I am very new to ruby, so please bear with me. 
I have tried to do it this way, which obviously is not working.

```
puts "Which test do you want to take?"

select = 0

while (select != 3)
  puts "Press 1 to take Geografi test." 
  puts "Press 2 to take Math test." 
  puts "Press 3 to take Religion test."
  puts "Press 3 to exit"
  select = gets.chomp.to_i

if (select == 1)
  gets.chomp = userinput
  userinput =`geografitest.txt`
  echo $userinput
end

if (select == 2)
  gets.chomp = userinput
  userinput =`matematiktest.txt`
  echo $userinput
  end


if (select == 3)
  gets.chomp = userinput
  userinput =`religionstest.txt`
  echo $userinput
end 
if (select > 4)
  puts "Not a correct selection"  

elsif (select == 4)
  puts "Goodbye" 
end 

end
abort
```

So my questions is now; 
How can i make the user choose what test to take? Can i make a variable instead of the textfile as i have tried, but in a different way? Or is there a smarter way?

And in what way is my class wrong and how do i fix it? I know its not the way to make it, but i simple cant get my head around how to make it right.

Please help a rookie out. 
Cheers!

Comment: additional question: Something might be wrong with my If/elsif statement when asking the user. How can i fix that aswell?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass file as dependency to you Test class based on user input with object constructor. Something like this

```rb
class Test
  attr_reader :correct_answers_count

  def initialize(file)
    @file = file
    @correct_answers_count = 0
  end

  #other code goes here
end

loop do
  case user_input = gets.chomp
  when '1'
    file_name = 'some_file1'
  when '2'
    file_name = 'some_file1'
  when '3'
    break
  else
    puts 'wrong variant'
  end

  test = Test.new(File.new(file_name, 'r'))
  test.display
end
```